# How can I calculate the average of a set of numbers in excel with a given max?

Tags: excel-formula

Good afternoon, I have a table of trials that I am trying to average. There are three trials being conducted (trial one = column B, trial 2 = column C, and trial 3 = column D). Each of these trials displays a number, which can be below or above 180. I need to average these three trials, but if the number is greater than 180, then I need the average to be calculated using 180 rather than the original number.

Example:

Trial 1 = 159; Trial 2 = 189; Trial 3 = 73

What I would like to do: (159 + 180 + 73)/3= 137.33

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option (array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B2:B4>180,180,B2:B4))
```

[image]